# How can i convert a dataset with ratios for a binary outcome to something suitable for logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, dummy-variable

I have a dataset that looks at each group of individuals in aggregate

```
Gender    Age    Region    Count    Affected
Male      18-24    CA      9843     384
Female    18-24    CA      8745     489
Male      35-24    CA      11923    381
```

and so on

I want to run logistic regression on the affected outcome which is essentially a binary response variable. I can recreate the data myself to look like

```
   Gender    Age    Region    Affected
    Male    18-24    CA     0
    Male    18-24    CA     0
(...)
    Male    18-24    CA     1
    Male    18-24    CA     1
(...)
    Female 18-24     CA    0
    Female 18-24     CA    0
```

and so on, basically, create a dummy variable for affected, or in other words, create a data set that for each group creates a row with a 0 for every person who has wasn't effected, and one row for every person. I can do this fairly easily by hand, but is there an easy way in R to convert this kind of binary ratio data into a dataset that can be used by logistic regression in R

Comment: Reason #213 why R is awesome, from `?glm`: *"For ‘binomial’ and ‘quasibinomial’ families the response can also be specified as a ‘factor’ (when the first level denotes failure and all others success) or **as a two-column matrix with the columns giving the numbers of successes and failures**."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
glm(cbind(Affected, Count - Affected) ~ Gender + Age, data = DF, family = binomial())
```

giving the following output:

```
Call:  glm(formula = cbind(Affected, Count - Affected) ~ Gender + Age, 
    family = binomial(), data = DF)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   GenderMale     Age35-24  
    -2.8263      -0.3777      -0.2069  

Degrees of Freedom: 2 Total (i.e. Null);  0 Residual
Null Deviance:      72.39 
Residual Deviance: 7.17e-13     AIC: 29.47
```

**Note:** Above we used this input:

```
Lines <- "Gender    Age    Region    Count    Affected
Male      18-24    CA      9843     384
Female    18-24    CA      8745     489
Male      35-24    CA      11923    381"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a big timesaver